# Database Reverse engineering wizard Fails

Tags: sql-server, azure, microsoft-visio, database-administration

I am using Visio 2019, trying to reverse engineer a Azure SQL server. I have successfully created multiple User data sources to use in the wizard using both our DB-admin user and my admin azure directory logins. The database credentials are successfully verified and the tables/views i want to reverse engineer are about to load in when i get the following:

Visio reverse engineer database wizard raises error:

> "Error! Cannot extract column definition for the table/view .  The definition is not
>
> available or you may not have sufficient privileges."

with a text box that says:

> "Could not find server "database name"* in sys.servers. Verify that
>   the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the
>   stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers."

I can neither find sys.servers nor run sp.addlinkedserver as it does not exist. though, sys.sysservers does exist.

I starred database name since instead of showing the target DB of "DB_2.0" it shows "DB_2" **which is not the full name of the Database.**

As i mentioned above i believe that i have sufficient privileges as i am the admin and using an admin username and password. So it may have something to do with not having the sys.servers table?

Answer (score 0):

Worked with MSFT support, they had me rename my database from DB_2.0 to DB_2. I created a new connection DSN and it worked perfectly afterwards. Apparently visio doesn't like the ".0" in a connection string. It would be nice if i could have eddited the connection string in a text file so I did not have to rename my entire DB.